# Sincronizar SeekBar cuando presiono botón físico de subir o bajar volumen

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

Este es mi código actual para subir y bajar el volumen mediante una seekBar, y todo va perfecto, el problema es que cuando utilizo los botones físicos del teléfono la SeekBar se queda fija y no se mueve a la par que el volumen del telefono. Actúa pero no se refresca digamos el seekBar.

Quiero que cuando utilice los botones del móvil para subir y bajar, se mueva la barra a la vez.

---

### Método que llamo para iniciar el control de volumen.

```
private void initControls() {
    try {


        volumeSeekbar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.volumen);
        audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        volumeSeekbar.setMax(audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));
        volumeSeekbar.setProgress(audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));


        volumeSeekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int progress, boolean arg2) {


                audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, progress, 0);

                if (progress > 10 ){

                    imagenVolumenAlto.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    imagenVolumenMedio.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    imagenVolumenBajo.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    imagenVolumenSilencio.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


                }else if (progress <= 10 && progress >= 5){

                    imagenVolumenAlto.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    imagenVolumenMedio.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    imagenVolumenBajo.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    imagenVolumenSilencio.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


                }else if (progress <= 3 && progress >= 1){

                    imagenVolumenAlto.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    imagenVolumenMedio.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    imagenVolumenBajo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    imagenVolumenSilencio.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


                }else if (progress == 0){

                    imagenVolumenAlto.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    imagenVolumenMedio.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    imagenVolumenBajo.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    imagenVolumenSilencio.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                }

            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

---

[image: Pantalla Radio de mi aplicacion]

Quiero que lo que se ve abajo se desplace a la vez que lo de arriba.

Comment: Nadie me puede echar una mano? =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo he solucionado añadiendo lo siguiente en la clase:

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP)
    {
        volumeSeekbar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.volumen);
        int index = volumeSeekbar.getProgress();
        volumeSeekbar.setProgress(index + 1);
        return true;
    } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN)
    {
        int index = volumeSeekbar.getProgress();
        volumeSeekbar.setProgress(index - 1);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Ahora cuando uso los botones del dispositivo se actualiza a la vez.